# Should we use a game developer tag for questions about a specific game?

Tags: discussion, tags

For questions about a specific game, should we use a tag for the developer of that game?  For example, in a question about Team Fortress 2, should there be a [valve] tag?

I'm thinking that, as this site expands, this would make it easier to get people from the game companies to get involved, because they could easily see what questions people have about their games.

Answer (score 10):

I vote **no**, because

- It doesn't represent the question - questions are typically about a *game*, not the company behind it, and so:
- I think it should be reserved for questions that actually deal directly with that company (e.g. how to I open an online account for that company).
- Sometimes a game can have multiple developers - this clutters the tags, and may create inconsistent tagging for the same game.
- Let's be honest - not everyone knows the developer of the game they want to ask about, or bother to write it if they know it. And that will create some inconsistency.
- It doesn't give a lot of added value, in my opinion - the only benefit I see for users is the ability to filter according to it when there's a specific company where the user in question is familiar with *all* their games.

Answer (score -1):

You have five tags available, so if you have a tag left I think it's useful to put it in there

But then which do you tag? The developer or the publisher? Often EA or Activision is much more recognizable, than the independent small developer.

Another issue is that if the developer is worthy of his/her own tag (Valve, Blizzard, Harmonix etc) their games are most likely to be renowned as well, so there's less need to advertise (go sell tags!) the developer.

But the best purpose of the developer tag would be for games-recommendation: like Game A from Developer X, you might also like their Games B & C.